# MS Access won't save file when trying to upgrade from 2002-2003 to 2016

Tags: microsoft-access

We have a customer with a lot of old access files that we are taking a look at. Honestly we don't deal with Access much but they are having performance issues with it so we decided to take a stab.

First thing I noticed is all the files are in Access 2002-2003 format and I wanted to try to see if we could get them upgraded to 2016. A lot of the mdb files are upgrading but a few won't.

We can open the problem mdb files and it works fine but when we try to Save As it just does nothing! You choose Save As (.accdb) and choose the folder, click Save and it does ABSOLUTELY NOTHING! No errors, no success at the bottom right and NO file is created at all. I've tested this on Access 2013 and 2016 with multiple computers so I'm thinking something in this mdb is causing it to not be able to save. Not cool that it doesn't give any errors or helpful notifications as to why it couldn't save. I have already tried a compact and repair database.

Answer (score 1):

The generic step is:

Convert an Access 2000 or Access 2002 - 2003 database to the .accdb format

To convert an Access 2000 or Access 2002 - 2003 database (.mdb) to the .accdb file format, you must first open the database by using Access 2007, Access 2010, Access 2013, or Access 2016, and then save it in the .accdb file format.

Click File, and then click Open.

Click the Access 2000 or Access 2002 - 2003 database (.mdb) that you want to convert.

> Note:  If the Database Enhancement dialog box appears, the database is
>   using a file format that is earlier than Access 2000. To continue, see
>   the section Convert an Access 97 database to the .accdb format.

Click File, click Save As, and then click Save Database As.

Choose the Access file type, and then click Save As.

If any database objects are open when you click Save As, Access prompts you to close them prior to creating the copy. Click Yes to make Access close the objects, or click No to cancel the entire process. If needed, Access will also prompt you to save any changes.

In the Save As dialog box, type a file name in the File name box, and then click Save.

Access creates the copy of the database, and then opens the copy. Access automatically closes the original database.

[Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098ddd31-5f84-4e89-8f44-db0cf7c11acd)

Comment: Yes. That does not work. It opens in 2002-2003 format with no issues. Save As and choose the new format and press save, it does nothing as mentioned above. No error, no new database saved.

Comment: @Jacob Can you test out with Access 2007 ?

Comment: I don't have 2007 but I can try to setup an environment when I find the downloads.